# JavaScript prototype inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I've been spending my past couple hours researching prototypical inheritance, but I'm left with conflicting/unclear answers on how it should be done. It seems to be *working* for how I'm using it right now.

```
Paper.Component = function(){}; // useless unless I can solve problem mentioned below?
Paper.Component.prototype = {
    isInBounds: function(x, y){
        // ...
    },
    setPosition: function(x, y){
        // ...
    },
    setSize: function(w, h){
        // ...
    }
};

Paper.Button = function(x, y, w, h, text){
    // ...
}
Paper.Button.prototype = Object.create(Paper.Component.prototype);
```

It also seems to have another problem; How can I have `Paper.Button` save it's constructor information (`x,y,w,h`) onto `Paper.Component` rather than on itself? I.e., how can every child of `Paper.Component` inherit and set these values?